# BIC criterion with negative minimized value of the likelihood function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, likelihood, bic

BIC criterion is defined as

BIC=$ k \ln(n)-2 \ln(L)$

where $k$ is the number of parameters, $n$ represents the number of observations and  L is the maximized value of the likelihood function of the model.

Can I use BIC criterion if I have minimized value of the likelihood function? What about negative minimized value of the likelihood function?